# Dimensions in html5 canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas, jcanvas

I have a problem with the HTML5 Canvas. I use jCanvas to add layers to an canvas but I have a problem with the sizes.

I have 2 rectangles a green one and a red one.
Now I want the red box touch the green left top corner.

Using the coordinate system I start green at coordinates 200, 200
then red has to start at 0,0 and the width and height has to be 200 and 200.
But that doesn't work

[Check this example](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/sandbox/?code=JCgnY2FudmFzJykKLmFkZExheWVyKHsKICB0eXBlOiAncmVjdGFuZ2xlJywKICBuYW1lOiAncmVkQm94JywKICBmaWxsU3R5bGU6ICcjYzMzJywKICB4OiAwLCB5OiAwLAogIHdpZHRoOiAyMDAsIGhlaWdodDogMjAwCn0pCi5hZGRMYXllcih7CiAgdHlwZTogJ3JlY3RhbmdsZScsCiAgbmFtZTogJ2dyZWVuQm94JywKICBmaWxsU3R5bGU6ICcjNTg1JywKICB4OiAyMDAsIHk6IDIwMCwKICB3aWR0aDogMTAwLCBoZWlnaHQ6IDEwMAp9KQouZHJhd0xheWVycygpOw==)

Why doesnt this work??

When I use [100x100 dimensions](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/sandbox/?code=JCgnY2FudmFzJykKLmFkZExheWVyKHsKICB0eXBlOiAncmVjdGFuZ2xlJywKICBuYW1lOiAncmVkQm94JywKICBmaWxsU3R5bGU6ICcjYzMzJywKICB4OiAwLCB5OiAwLAogIHdpZHRoOiAxMDAsIGhlaWdodDogMTAwCn0pCi5hZGRMYXllcih7CiAgdHlwZTogJ3JlY3RhbmdsZScsCiAgbmFtZTogJ2dyZWVuQm94JywKICBmaWxsU3R5bGU6ICcjNTg1JywKICB4OiAxMDAsIHk6IDEwMCwKICB3aWR0aDogMTAwLCBoZWlnaHQ6IDEwMAp9KQouZHJhd0xheWVycygpOw==) it does work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All depends on the origin of your layer. By default it is the center of the layer.
So to have the results you expect there are two solutions (exemples with layer 100*100) :

First in your case you have to calculate correct position from top left canvas origin to the middle of your object :

```
$('canvas')
.addLayer({
  type: 'rectangle',
  name: 'redBox',
  fillStyle: '#c33',
  x: 50, y: 50,//canvas origin to center (100/2)
  width: 100, height: 100
})
.addLayer({
  type: 'rectangle',
  name: 'greenBox',
  fillStyle: '#585',
  x: 150, y: 150,//canvas origin to center (100 of red layer + 100/2)
  width: 100, height: 100
})
.drawLayers();
```

Or you can set origin to top left corner by disable *fromCenter* property:

```
$('canvas')
.addLayer({
  type: 'rectangle',
  name: 'redBox',
  fillStyle: '#c33',
  fromCenter: false,
  x: 0, y: 0,
  width: 100, height: 100
})
.addLayer({
  type: 'rectangle',
  name: 'greenBox',
  fillStyle: '#585',
  fromCenter: false,
  x: 100, y: 100,
  width: 100, height: 100
})
.drawLayers();
```

Hope this help

Comment: @#$#@!! What an easy solution. I spend hours searching for a ratio or something. It hurts me that its so simple. Thanks!!!!!!